# Пример группировки данных в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Нужно в массиве данных получить суммарное значение по полю разделенных по группам.

Пример:

```
IEnumerable<Issue>
Member Issue.Member
decimal Issue.hours
```

Нужно пройти по массиву Issue, сгруппировать данные по member и для каждой группы сосчитать суммарное значение hours

Пытался следующим образом:

```
issues
.Where(w => w.Member != null)
.Group(g => g.Member)
.Select(s => {
 s.Key
 // Здесь могу получить только ключ, а как получить данные и дальше их начать суммировать?
});
```

По окончанию выборка должна содержать пару значений .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Группировка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx) поддерживает итерирование по ней, поэтому можно просто вызвать метод [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549046(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var data = issues
    .Where(m => m != null)
    .Group(g => g.Member)
    .Select(s => new { s.Key, Sum = s.Sum(i => i.hours) });

// или .Select(s => Tuple.Create(s.Key, s.Sum(i => i.hours)));
```

`data` будет содержать список объектов с ключом группировки и значением суммы для каждой группировки.

Comment: Только не `s.Member`, а `s.Key`.

Comment: @Vlad ага, спасибо. Поправил.

Answer (score 5):

Или так:

```
var data = from issue in issues
           group issue by issue.Member
           into g
           select new {g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(s => s.hours)};
```